# Laravel Migration System for database tables

Tags: php, laravel, migration, relational-database

Due to Laravel migration system, we can create database tables by running the following command lines.

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table

class CreateUserTable extends Migration {
  public function up() {
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('email')->unique();
      $table->string('name');
      $table->timestamps();
   });
 }

 public function down() {
   Schema::drop('users');
   }
 }

php artisan migrate
```

If I work with relational database and have two tables, A and B. Table A is related to table B by a foreign key. Is it possible to create such database tables with Laravel Migration System? Or do I need to configure the relationship in phpmyadmin manually?

Comment: In addition to the two answers below, I'd also add that it's perfectly acceptable to use `DB::statement()` in the migrations for complex SQL.

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible to create forgien keys in laravel migration

```
$table->foreign('fk_id')->references('primary_key')->on('fk_table')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set foreign keys etc using the schema see [here.](http://laravel.com/docs/schema#foreign-keys)

Example...

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Also if you are creating tables I would advise using [this site](http://laravelsd.com/) to help build your schema, much easier to visualise and work with.